# Create Drop Down Table (Not sure what the name would be)

Tags: html, css

I'm using HTML/CSS to create my portfolio and wanted a drop down menu with my certifications (Image below for reference).

[image: Drop Down reference Image.]

It might be a really obvious answer but could someone help me out with how I would do this.

Comment: This is usually called an [accordion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(GUI)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could use an existing UI kit version (such as [Bootstrap's Accordion component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/)), or spin your own using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, you might find the [native `<details>` disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) sufficient to your needs:

```css
details {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>How are you?</summary>
    Doing OK, thanks :)
</details>

<details>
    <summary>Some weather we're having, huh?</summary>
    I know!  I didn't know if I should bring a sweater or a t-shirt!
</details>
```

You'll want to make sure that the tag is semantically appropriate for your content, though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfun() {

  var a = document.getElementById("drop")

  if (a.style.display != 'none') {
    a.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    a.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
#drop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="myfun()"> This is dropdown. Click to drop down You can add an image like an arrow for better graphics </p>
<p id="drop"> this is the dropdown </p>
```

Comment: i think u should do it like the above guy as it is easier and doesnt require js

Comment: Welcome to SO!  For your reference, you can [create a runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in the body of your question to avoid the need for links to external services like CodePen.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I know it,  but for this particular problem, the stack snippet wasn't working

Comment: @WebDevDude I pasted your code (as a snippet) into the answer.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat ty dude!